# Could X-Cache: STALE affect Google rankings?

Tags: seo, google, ranking, cache, cache-control

Could the presence of `X-Cache: STALE` response header decrease my Google rankings ?
I am the second time when ... while working on cache servers configuration I see rankings drop even thou response time improves.
The onnly new thing I can think of, is the presence of `X-Cache: STALE` which might be interpreted by Google that content is not fresh ?

My config is like this: CloudFlare <-- Nginx cache server <-- My origin server

On origin server I set a `"Cache-Control: public, max-age=2"` and set nginx reverse proxy to `proxy_cache_use_stale` (use stale while updating pages, or in case of errors) which seems to work fine, end server always gets a fast cached page and servers updates pages in background, regardless of how slow background update is, the user always receives an instant cached page.

I can and probably will configure them to hide this `X-Cache: STALE` header from end user, but I was curious if anyone has experience or thoghts on this.